# Why can $d E$ be represented as $ I_\nu \vec{k} \cdot \vec{n} dA d\Omega d \nu dt$ in radiation?

Tags: radiation

The appropriate definition of specific intensity can be something as following:

Construct an area $dA$ with the normal direction of $\vec{n}$, and the direction of the ray is $\vec{k}$. Consider all rays passing through $dA$ whose direction is within a solid angle $d\Omega$ of the given ray. The energy crossing $dA$ in time $dt$ and in frequency range $d\nu$ is then defined by the relation
$$ dE = I_\nu \vec{k} \cdot \vec{n} dA d\Omega d\nu dt. $$
Considering both $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{n}$ are unit vectors, the formula can also be written as
$$ dE = I_\nu \cos \theta dA d\Omega d\nu dt, $$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{n}$.

[image]

I don't understand $I_\nu \cos \theta$ clearly.
In my oppion, the solid angle $d \Omega$ is so small that the rays within it can be seen as parallel. If so, the formula seems obvious. As for the rays that are in other directions, they can also be seen as parallel respectively. In short, a set of rays in many directions can be seen as many sets of parallel rays in different directions. If we want to know the total energy in all directions, we integrate the sets of the parallel rays that are in different directions.
Is what I think correct? If not, can you show me where I'm wrong?

Comment: $\theta$ is the angle between the unit vector $\hat{n}$, which is normal to the surface and the unit wave vector $\hat{k}$, which gives the direction of the ray. The factor $\cos\theta$ gets rid of the components parallel to the surface i.e. those that do not cross the surface. The rays within $d\Omega$ are "parallel" and they are all at the same angle $\theta$ with the normal vector.